# How to put a sprite in Unity5 without bugs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a sprite that i made in PaintNET:
[image]

and when i put it in Unity 5.1 (i'm newbie in unity) it shows like this:
[image]

is like bugged, i don't know how to solve this problem. I want to see the sprite like i made LOL. Thanks!

Comment: Put the images directly into your question, so that they remain if those gyazo links ever go dead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the importsettings of your Sprite and change Compression to "Uncompressed".